# geom_point plot with only number without circles

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot in R, is it possible to plot each point with a unique number but without circles surrounded? I tried to use color "white" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend `geom_text`.

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(50),y=rnorm(50),id=1:50)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+geom_text(aes(label=id))
```

[image]

Comment: Also `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` if overplotting is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show how to do it with `geom_text` **and/or** `geom_point`.

1. Using `geom_text` (recommended)

For this example I'll use the built-in dataset `mtcars` and let's pretend the numbers you want to display are the weights (`wt`) variable:

```
data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))

p + geom_text(aes(label = wt),
              parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

or if you want an example with truly unique numbers, we can just make up an index using `seq`:

```
data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))

p + geom_text(aes(label = seq(1:32)),
              parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

2. Using `geom_point`

While it would require more work, it actually *is* possible to do this with `geom_point`.

This is a [reference](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape) image of some of the shapes you can use with `geom_point`:

[image]

As you can see, shapes 48 to 57 are 0 to 9. You can leverage these shapes (and combinations of them to form an infinite amount of numbers) via `geom_point` like this:

```
d=data.frame(p=c(48:57))
ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(name="") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="") +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  geom_point(data=d, mapping=aes(x=p%%16, y=p%/%16, shape=p), size=5, fill="red")
```

[image]

Finally, a trivial example using `mtcars` + `geom_point` with arbitrary numbers:

```
d=data.frame(p=c(48:57,48:57,48:57,48,49))
attach(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="") +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  geom_point(data=d, mapping=aes(x=wt, y=mpg, shape=p), size=5, fill="red")
```

[image]