# Create Legend for geom_text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-text

I would like to create a scatter plot were each point is graphed as a number instead of a circle. I need a legend that maps the number label in the scatter plot to the sample name.

My current attempt uses this code:

```
plot<-ggplot(df_mds,aes(x=x,y=y,group=interaction(Group,Sample)))+geom_text(aes(label=Label,color=Group,group=Sample),show.legend =T)
plot<-plot+guide()
plot<-plot+labs(x="Leading logFC dimension 1", y="Leading logFC dimension 2")
```

Using this data:

[image: With the data in this dataframe]

And creates this graph:

[image: And produces this graph]

The graph above is almost exactly what I want except I need a legend mapping the values in the "Label" column to the values in the "Sample" column.

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285694/geom-point-plot-with-only-number-without-circles) but I don't know how to combine the different shapes to create new numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you paste your data (using `dput`) along with your question.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the ability to create a legend based on the `label=` aesthetic.  Unfortunately, the answer is that you cannot - at least not easily using `ggplot`.  I would suggest using alternative approaches.  Here I present two options using the following example dataset:

```
scatter.plot <- data.frame(
    sampleName=paste0('Sample_',1:18),
    x=sample(1:10, 18, replace=TRUE),
    y=sample(1:10, 18, replace=TRUE),
    id=1:18,
    grp=c(rep('Group A', 6), rep('Group B', 6), rep('Group C',6))
)
```

#### Use labels on your points and the `ggrepel` package to avoid overlapping labels.

Your sample names are short enough where it makes sense that you can add your labels on the plot itself.  It can get a bit crowded, so I would recommend using the `geom_text_repel` and `geom_label_repel` functions in the `ggrepel` package to help with overplotting.  Aesthetics and various parameters can be adjusted to your liking:

```
ggplot(scatter.plot, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=grp), size=2.5) +
    geom_text_repel(
        aes(label=sampleName), color='gray45',
        min.segment.length = 0, size=3,
        force=10, direction='y') +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### Use Color and Shape

Not sure if this would work for you, but if you adjust the shape for your group and shape for the sample, you can get a legend for each sample out of the box using `ggplot` fairly easily.  Of course, it needs color to be able to discriminate properly:

```
ggplot(scatter.plot, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=grp, color=sampleName), size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a fundamental reason why "label" aesthetics can not have its legend in ggplot? In case of long labels your first suggested workaround is not suitable. To solve this without introducing too many colors, I wanted to use abbreviations in the plot and "abbreviation: full label" in the legend. This could be done easily if legend could be created from label aesthetics.